# Как запретить редактирование размеров окна? (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, windowflags

Как можно сделать запрет на любое изменение окна?

Я нашёл в *Qt Creator* параметры `MinimalSize` и `Maximum Size`, благодаря ним смог сделать запрет на редактирование размеров окна, и все было бы хорошо, но когда я задал программе флаги:

```
Qt::Tool | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint
```

то это ограничение просто пропало, и не смотря на то. что `MaximumSize` и `MinimumSize` стоят в значении 330 и 380 пикселей изменять размер окна все равно возможно, так же пробовал вот такое решение:

```
QWidget::setFixedWidth(330);
QWidget::setFixedHeight(380);
```

но оно не дало никакого результата, как можно решить эту проблему?

P.S:

ос - Windows 10

версия Qt - 6

исходники проекта [тут](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SxC2AOZjqLI7jl0YKCRK-8xrepLFK-rO/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Методы `setFixedWidth`/`setFixedHeight`/`setFixedSize` должны работать и при данных флагах (У меня на qt-5 они заблокировали изменение соответствующих размеров окна). У Вас есть пример, на котором можно было бы воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum

Comment: @needKVAS добавил сам проект, но врятли дело в нем, наверное дело в Qt6

Comment: @S.Nick ваше решение действительно решило проблему, только вот появилась рамка вокруг приложения https://prnt.sc/0NSRbX-FVzyE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на свой вопрос, удалось достичь результата с помощью флага `Qt::WindowTitleHint`, это не совсем то что я хотел но в целом меня все устраивает при попытке разширить окно курсор появляеться, но вот само окно не разширяеться

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, что так, но не проверял.

```
myWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
```

[void QWidget::setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy horizontal, QSizePolicy::Policy vertical)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setSizePolicy-1)

[enum QSizePolicy::Policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum)

Comment: `QSizePolicy` используется при размещении виджета в layout-е. Если речь идёт об отдельном окне, то данный способ не возымеет эффекта.

Comment: к сожалению ваше решение мне не помогло